# Display search results within the same page

Tags: search, forms, 404-error

## Problem

I have a page on my site where I need to do additional searching within that page.  I am using the default way of WordPress searching with `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` for my main header search, which works great.

I created another HTML form on my page, not using the default PHP method, for the additional searching like so:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" id="searchform" method="get">
    <div>
        <label for="s" class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="photo_group" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchsubmit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I use the `type=hidden` for getting the custom post type that I want to search through:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="photo_group" />
```

which gives me a link that looks similar to:

```
http://mywebsite.com/?s=search&post_type=photo_group
```

## Question

When I use the new search form created on the page, it uses the default search.php to display the results.  How can I display the search results of the custom post type search, lets say in a `div` on the same page?

I've tried creating a new page template that would display the results with no success, could this be the right way of doing it and I just did it wrong?

## ***Edit***

I'm trying the solution of sanchothefat. Does this look right? This is my whole div for my search results and search query.

```
<div id="photo-search">
    <h2>Search Photos:</h2>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="searchform" method="get">
        <div>
            <label for="s" class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</label>
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="photo_group" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchsubmit" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php if( isset( $_REQUEST['search'] ) ) {
        query_posts( array(
        's' => $_REQUEST['search'],
        'post_type' => $_REQUEST['photo_group'],
        'paged' => $paged
        ));

        if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_title();
            the_content();                      
        endwhile; endif;

        wp_reset_query(); 
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

I get 404 error page not found when running through the search.

Comment: Did my solution work for you in the end?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, so, in a way it did help me out. Thank you much.

Comment: what was your solution?  I am trying to do the same thing - display the search results of a custom post in the same page as the search request and I keep getting a 404 page when I click submit

Comment: I was faced with the same solution and found that having post_type=my_cpt_post_type in the url was causing the problem.  Much the same as changing the default input name from 's' to 'search' in the answer below I change my hidden input from 'post_type' to 'p_type' and that solved my problem.  Then in your query you can use 'post_type' => $_REQUEST[ 'p_type' ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option if you want to show search results within a page context you'll need to do a custom loop, otherwise you won't be able to access the page information.

Change the input with the name `s` to something else like `search` or `q` to stop wordpress from doing it's usual built in search.

Next change the form `action` parameter to the current page's URL. You can use `<?php get_permalink(); ?>` for that.

The loop you need to do is as follows:

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'search' ] ) ) {
          // run search query
          query_posts( array(
             's' => $_REQUEST[ 'search' ],
             'post_type' => $_REQUEST[ 'post_type' ],
             'paged' => $paged
             )
          );

        // loop
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :
            // loop through results here
        endwhile; endif;

        // return to original query
        wp_reset_query();
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have to change `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :` to `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` in order to avoid infinite loop (not sure why). Maybe because I'm rendering custom template inside with `get_template_part(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the query before it gets processed:

```
add_action('parse_query', function($query){

  // not the search request
  if(!$query->is_search)
    return;

  // validate post type here (you should provide a white-list)
  $post_type = isset($_GET['post_type']) ? sanitize_key($_GET['post_type']) : false;

  // adjust the query
  if($post_type && post_type_exists($post_type))
    $query->set('post_type', $post_type);

});
```

This will get you posts matching the requested post type.

If you want to query multiple post types just pass an array instead: `array('post', 'page', $post_type)`. And to group posts based on the type, check the type within the loop, and store your CPTs inside a temporary array, which you iterate after the normal posts have been displayed.

Comment: Is this something I put in my functions.php file or simply directly on the page?

Comment: yes, either that or a build a new plugin and paste the code into it